# How can I get only the JAR file?

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository, pom.xml

I had two projects using the same code for a functionality. To avoid that, I isolated this code in a new project so the two projects can use this functionality by indicating the dependency in their pom.xml file. So, once that I created the new project with the repeated, I save in innersource as a maven repository.

In the pom.xml file of both projects I used  tag with  and  inside to indicate where is the repository. When I update the projects the dependency is downloaded from the remote repository and it works, but when I saw the Maven dependencies section of my project, where all needed JARs are, I found that is not only downloaded the JAR file of the third project, but there is a folder with the project.

So how I can get the JAR and not a folder?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "Maven dependencies section"? The maven local repository? What do you mean by "a folder with the project"?

Comment: Could you add the pom.xml files?